# atomic operations on shared memory

Tags: c, cuda, atomic, gpu-shared-memory

How can I do an atomic operation on a shared memory?
I have something similar to this:

```
__shared__ int a[10];
//set a
if(tid<5)
  a[2]++;
```

Therefore 5 threads are incrementing `a`. How can I do this?
I know that in this way I am serializing the execution of 5 threads, but how does this effect the warp? would all the threads in the warp be serialized or just the first 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `a[2]++` with

```
atomicAdd( a + 2, 1 );
```

if you can make a unsigned, you might prefer to use `atomicInc()` instead, but either one is going to kill performance.